# `std::remove` in template function causing problems with `vector.begin()` being `const`

Tags: c++, templates

The error message:
"binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"

The error seems to be because I'm giving `std::remove` a `const` value for the first argument, but I don't see exactly how `v.begin()` being unmodifiable would cause problems, nor why this error only occurs if the type of the vector is templated, as opposed to a known type vector.

The template function:

```
// Erases a every element of a certain value from a vector
template <typename T>
std::vector<T> eraseElement(std::vector<T> v, T elem)
{
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator newEnd = std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), elem);
    v.erase(newEnd, v.end());
    return v;
}
```

An example of the way I'm calling the template function:

```
struct exampleStruct
{
    int x;
}

std::vector<exampleStruct> v;
exampleStruct elem;
elem.x = 2451;
v.push_back(elem);

v = eraseElement(v, elem);
```

Comment: You have to provide `bool operator==(const exampleStruct& other) const` to compare exampleStruct instances.

Comment: it isnt the issue, but it is important to understand that there is a difference between a const iterator and a const_iterator. The first cannot be modified the latter refers to an element that cannot be modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> nor why this error only occurs if the type of the vector is templated, as opposed to a known type vector.

It [also occurs](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6b893fba9836247) if you substitute `exampleStruct` manually.

```
std::vector<exampleStruct> eraseElement(std::vector<exampleStruct> v, exampleStruct elem)
{
    auto newEnd = std::remove(v.begin(), v.end(), elem);
    v.erase(newEnd, v.end());
    return v;
}
```

That's because there isn't an `operator==` for `exampleStruct`. You probably want something like

```
bool operator==(const exampleStruct & lhs, const exampleStruct & rhs)
{
    return lhs.x == rhs.x;
}
```

or with a C++20 implementation

```
struct exampleStruct 
{
    int x;
    friend bool operator==(const exampleStruct &, const exampleStruct &) = default;
};
```

Comment: Oh. I'm not too experienced with the more non C adjacent parts of C++, (I mostly use it as "C with OOP") so I had no idea that there's not a default equality operator on types you declare yourself. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> The error message: "binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const _Ty' (or there is no acceptable conversion)"
>
> The error seems to be because I'm giving std::remove a const value for the first argument

Probably not. The error is because you're probably using `T` that is not equality comparable (in other words, there is no equality operator - which is the binary `operator==` - that would accept the operands). Constness should not be a problem because an equality comparable type should accept const arguments for comparison.

`exampleStruct` in particular is not equality comparable. One way to solve your problem is to make it equality comparable. You can do that by defining the binary `operator==` for the type. I recommend following approach:

```
struct exampleStruct
{
    int x;
    friend auto operator<=>(const exampleStruct&, const exampleStruct&) = default;
};
```

Another way to solve the problem is to not use `std::remove`, but to use `std::remove_if` instead. That way you can provide the condition to remove the element which doesn't have to compare the elements for their equality.

> nor why this error only occurs if the type of the vector is templated, as opposed to a known type vector.

I highly doubt this. `exampleStruct` remains non-comparable whether `eraseElement` is a template or not.

Comment: I had only tested the type with built in types, and I had no idea that there's no default equality operator for types you declare yourself. Caleth's answer answered my question fairly well, but so does yours. Thanks.